# Aadding .eps image to PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am able to create a PDF from image using the code below. But I received an error when the image format is .eps

Here is my code:

```
string imagelocation = @"C:\Users\Desktop\1.eps";
string outputpdflocation = @"C:\Users\Desktop\outputfromeps.pdf";
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 42, 35);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(outputpdflocation, FileMode.Create));
    doc.AddTitle("Document Title");

    doc.Open();

    iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagelocation);
    image1.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;

    image1.ScaleToFit(700, 900);

    image1.SetAbsolutePosition((PageSize.A4.Width - image1.ScaledWidth) / 2, (PageSize.A4.Height - image1.ScaledHeight) / 2);
    doc.Add(image1);
    doc.Close();
}
```

But now it says .eps is not a recognized format.

So my solution in mind is convert the eps to another format.

I found the following code from Microsoft.

And here is the code:

```
System.Drawing.Image image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Desktop\1.eps");

// Save the image in JPEG format.
image1.Save(@"C:\Users\Programmer\epsoutput.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

But it gives me this error:

> Out of memory

So how can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: EPS is not supported in iText, so there's no answer to your question. That's no reason to down-vote the question; I'll up-vote to get the score back to 0.

Comment: You should post anothet question that is C# specific, for instance showing how you try to convert an EPS file to a PNG file using C#. (Don't convert the lossless EPS to the lossy JPEG format.)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie sir. so a solution is to convert the EPS file to a PNG file? thank you.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the best way. Unfortunately, I don't know how to convert EPS to PNG in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) to convert an EPS to PDF by calling to it from the command line in C#.

You can use the below method once you have installed Ghostscript, and you need to supply the path for it

```
public bool ConvertEpsToPdfGSShell(string epsPath, string pdfPath, 
                                   string ghostScriptPath)
    {
        var success = true;
        var epsQual= (char)34 + epsPath + (char)34;

        var sComment = "-q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o " + 
        (char)34 + pdfPath + (char)34 + " " + (char)34 + epsPath+ (char)34;

        var p = new Process();

        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo {FileName = ghostScriptPath};

        if (File.Exists(psi.FileName) == false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Ghostscript does not exist in the path 
             given: " + ghostScriptPath);
        }

        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = true;
        psi.Arguments = sComment;
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        if (p.ExitCode == 0) return success;
        success = false;

        try
        {
            p.Kill();
        }

        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            p.Dispose();
        }


        return success;
    }
```